# WPF display message instead of menu items in menu when bound menus list is empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a menu that looks something like this:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="menu" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Style="{StaticResource ItemStyle}">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        ...
    </MenuItem.Header>
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="PropertyNameOne" Value="{Binding}"/>
            <Setter Property="PropertyNameTwo" Value="{Binding}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

`Items` is a `NotifyingCollection`. However, when the `Items` list is empty, I would like to display a message, like "No items in menu.", instead of the current behavior, which is a tiny little empty box. Is there a way to do this just in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a DataTrigger to set the ItemContainerStyle:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="menu">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        ...
    </MenuItem.Header>
    <MenuItem.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem} BasedOn="{StaticResource ItemStyle}">
              <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Items}">
              <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle">
                   <Setter.Value>
                        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                <Setter Property="PropertyNameOne" Value="{Binding}"/>
                                <Setter Property="PropertyNameTwo" Value="{Binding}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                   </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}">
                      ... Alternate Content ItemsSource and ttemContainerStyle
                  </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
          ...
```

That's the general idea anyway, I'm sure you can fill in the details with your particular needs. (i.e., defining a disabled child MenuItem with your placeholder text)